# Can't find Hyperlink control in DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

I need to disable an `<asp:HyperLink>` in each of my rows based on a certain condition when the page loads.
So far, I'm not having any luck...

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To CourseData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If CourseData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("completedyn") = "yes" Then
            CourseData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("completedyn") = "Complete"
        Else
            CourseData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("completedyn") = "Incomplete"
        End If
    Next

    grdCourses.DataSource = CourseData
    grdCourses.DataBind()

    For i As Integer = 0 To grdCourses.Items.Count - 1
        If grdCourses.FindControl("hypEnter") IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim hypEnter As HyperLink = CType(grdCourses.FindControl("hypEnter"), HyperLink)

            If CourseData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("completedyn") = "Incomplete" Then
                hypEnter.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    Next


    <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="grdCourses">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="modulename" HeaderText="Module Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="completedyn" HeaderText="Status"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="completeddate" HeaderText="Date Completed"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypEnter" Text="View Module" NavigateUrl='<%# "View.aspx?mod=" + Eval("moduleid").ToString()%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </asp:DataGrid>
```

The `FindControl()` method never changes.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be on the right path, but you're missing looking in each row. My VB.net is rusty, but I believe you want to add .Items(i) in a few places in your loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To grdCourses.Items.Count - 1
    If grdCourses.Rows(i).FindControl("hypEnter") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim hypEnter As HyperLink = CType(grdCourses.Rows(i).FindControl("hypEnter"), HyperLink)

        If CourseData.Tables(0).Rows(i)("completedyn") = "Incomplete" Then
            hypEnter.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You're half right, I was missing looking in each row. The proper syntax would be `grdCourses.Rows(i).FindControl("hypEnter")` ... For some reason, VS2010E seemed to be missing the `.Rows()` property which is why I got so very stuck. Marked as answer anyway, thanks for the response.